# MySQL related items query

Tags: mysql, database

I have related products table like this:

```
product_id | related_product_id
         1 | 2
         1 | 3
         1 | 4 
         2 | 1
         3 | 1
         4 | 1
```

But instead I would like to insert new related product ids so they all match. I.E. If product 1 has 2,3,4 I wan't that products 2,3,4 also have the same related ids which are missing.

Not sure how it's called but is this possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT` query as the source of data in an `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO related_products (product_id, related_product_id)
SELECT r1.product_id, r2.related_product_id
FROM related_products AS r1
CROSS JOIN related_products AS r2
WHERE r1.product_id != 1
AND r2.product_id = 1
```

This join will get all of product 1's related products and combine them with all the other product IDs.

Comment: Thanks. This is more complex, but it does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this query a try (untested, make a backup first!):

```
insert into related_products (product_id,related_product_id) (select related_product_id, product_id from related products);
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can put the `select` part in parentheses like that when you use it in an `INSERT`.

Comment: Yes, fastest method for my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to user bidirectional condition to get the inter related products. For example if you apply condition on single column product_id, you will not get visa-versa result. But, if you check that condition on both column, you will get the result.

For example:

```
select related_product_id, product_id from products where related_product_id=1 OR product_id=1
```

This will give your related product id in either related_product_id or product_id.

Same you can get it for product 2 i.e.

```
select related_product_id, product_id from products where related_product_id=2 OR product_id=2
```

This will give all your related product id in either related_product_id or product_id.